# Retracts of finite-by-abelian groups

Tags: group-theory

A retraction of a group $G$ onto a subgroup $H$ is an epimorphism from $G$ to $H$ which is the identity on $H$.

Let $A$ be an infinite free abelian group and $D$ a direct factor of $A$. Then there exists a retraction of $A$ onto $D$.

**Question**: Does something equivalent hold for f.g. finite-by-abelian groups?

To be more precise:
Let now $A$ be (infinite) finite-by-abelian, i.e. there exists a finite normal subgroup $E$ of $A$ such that $A/E$ is f.g. free abelian. Let $D$ be a direct factor of $A/E$, hence there exists a retraction from $A/E$ onto $D$.
Does there exists a retraction from $A$ onto $\pi^{-1}(D)$, where $\pi:A \to A/E$ is the canonical projection?

Comment: I think if $A = \langle x,y,z \mid z^2=[x,z]=[y,z]=1, [x,y]=z \rangle$ and $E = \langle z \rangle$ then there is no such retraction for the direct factor $\langle yE \rangle$ of $A/E$.